# Simple Flex Program

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

Given a string -> The # 1 Temprature is 32CELSIUS

I Should print output -> The # 1 Temprature is 64FAHRENHEIT

I know it is not the correct conversion but that is not the point i am just suppose to double the value in front of celsius and return it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
%}
digit    [0-9]
celsius   "CELSIUS"
%%

{digit}+{celsius}        {printf("FAHRENHEIT");}


%%

int main(void)
{
  yylex();
  return 0;
}
```

This is the code i have so far i am kind of lost on how to convert the number since  i am not suppose to convert any number but only the one that is front of the world Celsius. Can anyone guide me

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to print 64; the correct temperature corresponding to 32 degrees Celsius is 89.6 degrees Fahrenheit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted works for me as expected. All you need to do is add a call to `sscanf()` (right before the call to `printf()`) with `yytext` as the first argument. This will allow you to store the integer in a variable, which you can then double and print back out via your `printf()` call.

Change:

```
{digit}+{celsius}        {printf("FAHRENHEIT");}
```

To:

```
{digit}+{celsius}        { int x; sscanf(yytext,"%d",&x); printf("%dFAHRENHEIT",x*2);}
```

If you want to match a float instead of an int, change your match rule to the following:

```
{digit}+.{digit}+{celsius}
```

Comment: is it possible for you to show how to do this? i am new to flex .

Comment: Here is documentation on sscanf: [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/). Here is a tutorial showing how to use yytext in flex: [link](http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html).

Comment: Thanks a ton and just had a quick question if that int was instead a float what would i do?

Comment: You're welcome. Please see the update. Does that make sense? For how to use sscanf on floats, see "man 3 sscanf" in Linux, or the link above to the sscanf documentation. Let me know if this doesn't make sense.